# Get country from coordinates in linux

Tags: gps, debian

I have a file that changes every now and then which contains gps coordinates. I would like to get the country in which those coordinates fall. Software should be running on a headless debian 8 machine and produce a plain text output.

Comment: See this related question: [Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the city/country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country)

Comment: Great solution, I didn't see it. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355022/1771479) you can use [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=13) which returns a json string. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script) I created a script that returns a country - if there is one - based on the coordinates:

```
import sys
import urllib, json

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print("Requires parameters: longitude latitude")
    exit(0)

def locToCountry(coord_long,coord_lat):
    # create url and open
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s&sensor=true" % (coord_long,coord_lat)
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    # check if there is data
    if len(data['results'])==0:
        print("ERROR: no country found")
        return ""

    # print data
    subdata =  data['results'][0]['address_components']

    # search for the country name
    for d in subdata:
        if 'country' in d['types']:
            return d["long_name"]

    print("WARNING: no country found")
    return ""


# call function
country = locToCountry(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
# print on screen
print("%s, %s => %s" % (sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],country))
```

Now you can run the script and it return the name of the country (if there is one):

```
> loctocountry.py 43 -3 
43, -3 => Spain
> loctocountry.py 40.7 -73.9
40.7, -73.9 => United States
```